# Touchpad right click doesn't work on touchpad, only the buttons above it. Thinkpad E480 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, 18.04

Installed fresh 18.04 LTS. Everything works fine except the touchpad. Thinkpad has toucpad buttons above it and they work fine, but the buttons under touchpad at the bottom only work as one left click. There is no option in settings to change that, it did work on Fedora 27 though. Is there anything I can change to add this funcionality?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, Ubuntu 18.04 currently defaults to "Mac" behavior on the touchpad. The technical details is that Ubuntu defaults libinput touchpads to "clickfingers" behavior.

To revert that, run this in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas
```

Comment: When you find a duplicate, flag it as a duplicate, don't verbatim copy the answer from the other question.