# Right click of touchpad is not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, dell, 18.04

In my Dell Inspiron 15 laptop I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 but the right click of my mousepad is not working at all.

What is the reason and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry the ubuntu version i've installed is 18.04

Comment: See these: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029444/right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right click not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029444/right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is the issue in Ubuntu! Right now i too cant able to find the way to make it work but as you have a laptop, try Double finger tap its working fine for me and also comfortable than clicking!

Comment: Hi Mrinal. You should probably note that it's more of an alternative/workaround and not a direct solution. But it's great that your suggestion was able to help the OP!