# Why does my touchpad right-button behave as left-button in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

Recently the  touchpad right-button stopped working as such and instead started behaving a left-button. For example, when I select text and right-click, instead of the expected context menu, the text gets deselected.

My *mouse's* right-button does work as expected.

It's a Dell Inspiron 7577 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Josua, you changed your question!! What you now describe is right other than the first other, because you said that the left and right button behave the same!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right click not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029444/right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad

Comment: @abu_bua " you said that the left and right button behave the same". That is still true. Doesn't the text say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it without installing gnome tweaks using

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad clickmethod "areas"
```

To set it back use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method "fingers"
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here is the answer](https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/).

Summary:

1. Ubuntu 18.04 changed touchpad behavior: By default, you "right-click" by tapping with two fingers.
2. You can get back the right-button 
   by installing `gnome-tweaks`, then *Keyboard and Mouse* -> *Area*.

Comment: sorry, showed you 1st the wrong way; i've myself disabled the finger function but didn't recognized it. Deleted the wrong answer.

Comment: +1 for info about two finger tap for right click.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you reversed them. Go into Settings, then Keyboard & Mouse. At the top you'll see where you can select which is your 'main mouse button'. Click left and then you're all set!

Comment: There was no reversal. I had no rightclick functionality at all, just leftclick from both sides of the touchpad

Comment: That's odd. I don't know then, sorry.

Comment: @alphaWold No problem, the issue was solved; see above