# Touchpad physical right button identified as left

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I am using an ASUS K501UXM.300 with Ubuntu 18.04 and having problems with the touchpad.

The right physical button is identified as a left click. To be more specific, when I run

```
xinput --test "TOUCHPAD NAME"
```

and press either the left or the right button of the touchpad, I get from both the same, that is

```
button press 1
```

If I check the button listing through

```
xinput --get-button-map "TOUCHPAD NAME"
```

I get

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

The button 3 is activated when I use one of the options chosen with Tweaks or with the command line

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'COMMAND'
```

These are the solutions of  [No secondary button (right click) on touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad) which "emulate" the right click, e.g. through a double-fingers tap, and are not what I am looking for. I would like to have my physical right button  to work as button 3 and not as button 1.

Just for completeness,

- before upgrading to ubuntu 18.04 everything was working normal
- it's not a hardware problem since if I boot with Windows, the right click works as right click
- with an usb mouse or with an usb keyboard with touchpad the right clicks work as expected (i.e. they give me back button 3 when running the test)

Can anyone help?

Cheers

EDIT: not sure how and why but it is working now, although I didn't change anything...maybe some minor update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No secondary button (right click) on touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad)

Comment: Thanks, but none of those solutions works. They only allow me to emulate the right click (with a double-finger tapping, for instance) but do not set the physical right button to work as a right click.