# Right Click Not Working

Tags: mouse, tap-to-click

I am new to use ubuntu version 18.04.1. After installing right click is not working however i am able to use  when i use external mouse, But built in mouse is not working.
Please help me 
System Details - Dell Vostro 3446 64 bit architecture.

Comment: By "*built-in mouse*" do you mean the laptop's touchpad?

Comment: Yes Dear. I am talking about laptop touchpad

Comment: See these: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029444/right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad

Answer (score 0):

By built-in mouse, do you mean the trackpad? If yes you probably need to configure your trackpad to right click as you usually do.

To do so you can go to System > Preferences > Mouse > Touchpad

More information here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Comment: Hello Dear, Thank you for your suggestion. I am not able to get 'System' in my setting. can you tell me how can i reach to that location. Did you mean System means Setting?

Comment: Do you confirm you have Ubuntu with Gnome desktop?

Comment: Did you find a way? I was asking because depending on your graphical environment (KDE, Mate, XFCE...), the menu can be somewhere else.