# Touchpad on Dell XPS-15-9500 with Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS

Tags: 18.04, dell, xps

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS on my Dell XPS-15-9500. I have noticed that physical left and right clicks do not seem to work on my touchpad. For instance, when using a scroll bar, I normally would click and then drag the bar to move. This action instead causes the cursor to freeze. Tapping the touchpad does result in left click behavior and two finger tapping results in right click behavior. I have installed gnome-tweaks and enabled "area" mode as per this post: [No secondary button (right click) on touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad). However, I have not found a solution to recover right/left click behavior I described above. I have unsuccessfully searched for a solution and have found mostly ways of recovering touchpad functionality after updates. In summary, how does one enable left and right "physical" click behavior in Ubuntu 18.04?

Edit 1: As requested in the comments, here is the output of `xinput`:

[image]

Comment: Please add output of `xinput` command to your question. You wrote a lot, but didn't mention what is the touchpad.

Comment: Found this which doesn't answer question but provides information on your platform: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?probe=f44222bfc5

Comment: https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Dell-XPS-15-9500-erratic-trackpad/td-p/7633189